# Is there a Xamarin.iOS equivalent of Java's GlyphVector or .NET's GraphicsPath?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, vector-graphics, text-rendering

Using Xamarin.iOS, (or just the iOS API) I need to get the outline path of text as rendered in some typeface. The exact outline is needed because I'm going to tesselate the outlines and apply 2D and 3D transformations to them.

In Java, this is straightforward by turning rendered text into a Shape (via GlyphVectors).

In GDI (.NET) this can be done with System.Drawing.GraphicsPath, adding text and getting the path. This is not available in Xamarin.iOS.

Is there a straightforward way to create paths for rendered text in iOS or Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MonoTouch.CoreText.CTFont.GetPathForGlyph` overloads that returns instances of `CGPath` are likely what you're looking for. It maps to the native [`CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontCreatePathForGlyph) API (for further documentation / samples).

You'll need to iterate your string (for each glyph) and create subpaths - but you should end up with your string as a vector (and be able to further transform then as you need).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It saved me a lot of time, as I'm not really familiar with iOS's API and frameworks. Anyway, I created the following demo based on your suggestion. It's written for clarity, not production: https://gist.github.com/johnsogg/2bab311ea798fd301084